# Show checkbox value in a child table in JavaScript and CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a problem in fetching exact value of the checkbox to a table in codeigniter. my checkbox was in the database table and when when i check the it show the last checkbox item (pls see the image below).

Check Box

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php foreach ($monthList as $key => $value) { ?>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkboxmth">
        <input id="chkAdd" type="checkbox" name="month_id" value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" <?php echo set_checkbox('month_id', $value['id']); ?> ><?php echo $value['type'] ?>
        </label>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
     <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('month_id'); ?></span>
```

The table where the checkbox will be append

```
<div class="box-body col-md-12" style="padding-top: 20px;">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="feeMasterEntryTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Month</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Penalty</th>
                <th class="text-right"></th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="form-horizontal" id="TextBoxContainer" role="form"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$(document).on("click", "#chkAdd", function () {
    var lenght_div = $('#TextBoxContainer').length;
    var div = GetDynamicTextBox(lenght_div);
    $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
});
$(document).on(function(){
    var values = "";
    $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
        values += $(this).val() + "\n";
    });
});
});

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
var month = '<?php echo set_value('month_id', $value['type']); ?>';
var startDate = '<?php echo set_value('startDate', $value['start_date']); ?>';
var endDate = '<?php echo set_value('endDate', $value['end_date']); ?>';
var amount = $('#amount').val();
var penalty = $('#penalty').val();
var row = "";
$('#chkAdd:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
row += '<tr class="tableGroup app">';
row += '<td class="mailbox-name">'+month+'</td>';
row += '<td class="mailbox-name">'+startDate+'</td>';
row += '<td class="mailbox-name">'+endDate+'</td>';
row += '<td class="mailbox-name" contenteditable="true">'+amount+'</td>';
row += '<td class="mailbox-name">'+penalty+'</td>';
row += '</tr>';
});
return row;
}
```

Screenshot of the table:

[image]

Comment: not getting core issue, but first don't use id "chkAdd" to bind event as this will only work for first checkbox or will not work for any of checkboxes., use class instead. Also why you are using set_value while assigning value in JS. Jquery event is working for only last most probbaly  due to duplicate ids

Comment: Thank you very much for responding in my question, I am just new in jquery I dont now what do do in regard of addending a checkbox value for a database table. please enlighten me more